# Angular unit-testing idea

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm a newbie in the world of web development and especially of unit testing since it wasn't my main subject during self-studying. Now I have to write unit-tests to my Angular code and I'm curious *what* I should test. Whether it should be only functions which do some calculations or should I also test some UI behaviour (e.g. check whether button really becomes disabled as expected or similar. Yep I know about e2e but it's more global I think).

So to make it clear what the question is about is "what should I test in unit-tests" (specifically Angular if it differs).

Because, I've seen the basic tests generated by CLI which are about 'should create' what seems ridiculous in terms of inability of app to compile if it's not working and Karma does need app to compile.

Comment: The generated tests by the CLI test the generated component: a generated component does nothing useful, but only provides the minimal boilerplate for the component. Same for the test: it doesn't do anything useful, but provides the minimum boilderplate. Just as you change the code of the component to make it do something useful, you should change the code of the test, too. The rest of your question is opinion-based: the more you test, the more you can be confident that your code does what it's supposed to do, but the more time it takes to write and maintain the tests.

Comment: Does it make any sense to keep these 'should create' working? Because it requires either importing all the components and services it has or making mock components and mock tests.

Comment: You'll have to do that for any other test, too won't you?